# Is it normal to find half of textbook's exercises extremely challenging?

Tags: soft-question

I'm taking a measure-theoretic probability course next semester and after looking at the exercises in the first section, I have only been able to solve about half of them.

My question is: should this be cause for concern? Or is it normal to find textbook exercises so challenging? I'm referring to the Billingsley textbook.

Comment: Yes. They are challenging because you are learning the material, and aren't expected to solve everything instantaneously. If you could, the textbook probably isn't for you.